# When to use waitForNextUpdate rather than act + jest.advanceTimersByTime?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-hooks-testing-library

There is an example on [advanced-hooks#async](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks#async) doc.

I am confused about how does `waitForNextUpdate` works. I made two test cases to compare `waitForNextUpdate` and `act()` + `jest.advanceTimersByTime()`.

`index.ts`:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

export function useCounter(initialValue = 0) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialValue);
  const increment = () => setCount((x) => x + 1);
  const incrementAsync = useCallback(() => setTimeout(increment, 100, [increment]);
  const reset = useCallback(() => setCount(initialValue), [initialValue]);
  return { count, increment, incrementAsync, reset };
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { useCounter } from './';

jest.setTimeout(5 * 1000);

describe('waitForNextUpdate  V.S. jest-advancedTimersByTime', () => {
  test('should pass by using jest.advancedTimersByTime', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useCounter());
    result.current.incrementAsync();
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(100);
    });
    expect(result.current.count).toBe(1);
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  test('should pass by using waitForNextUpdate', async () => {
    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useCounter());
    result.current.incrementAsync();
    await waitForNextUpdate();
    expect(result.current.count).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```
 PASS  issues/waitForNextUpdate-vs-jest-advancedTimersByTime/index.test.ts
  waitForNextUpdate  V.S. jest-advancedTimersByTime
    ✓ should pass by using jest.advancedTimersByTime (13 ms)
    ✓ should pass by using waitForNextUpdate (107 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.373 s, estimated 14 s
```

Both test cases pass. The only difference I found is that if I increase the delay for `setTimeout` to `1000 * 10`, the test case which uses `waitForNextUpdate` will fail.

```js
// useCounter
//...
const incrementAsync = useCallback(() => setTimeout(increment, 1000 * 10), [increment]);
//...
```

```
// first test case
// ...
jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000 * 10);
// ...
```

```sh
 FAIL  issues/waitForNextUpdate-vs-jest-advancedTimersByTime/index.test.ts (10.554 s)
  waitForNextUpdate  V.S. jest-advancedTimersByTime
    ✓ should pass by using jest.advancedTimersByTime (19 ms)
    ✕ should pass by using waitForNextUpdate (1006 ms)

  ● waitForNextUpdate  V.S. jest-advancedTimersByTime › should pass by using waitForNextUpdate

    Timed out in waitForNextUpdate after 1000ms.

      at waitForNextUpdate (node_modules/@testing-library/react-hooks/lib/core/asyncUtils.js:102:13)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.112 s
```

So what's the difference between `waitForNextUpdate` and `act()` + `jest.advanceTimersByTime()`? What kind of scene I can only use `waitForNextupdate` rather than `act()` + `jest.advanceTimersByTime()`?

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0"
```

Comment: `incrementAsync` is missing a closing bracket on setTimeout.

Comment: I got the answer i was looking for from your question +1

Answer (score 0):

`waitForNextUpdate` is not related to time, but state of your hook

> Wrapping incrementAsync in act() is not necessary since the state updates happen asynchronously during await waitForNextUpdate(). The async utilities automatically wrap the waiting code in the asynchronous act() wrapper.

Jest's `advanceTimersByTime` taps into the actual `setTimeout` or `setInterval` instances:

> When this API is called, all timers are advanced by msToRun milliseconds. All pending "macro-tasks" that have been queued via setTimeout() or setInterval(), and would be executed during this time frame, will be executed.